# using html list elements with switch stament and binding the list with database

Tags: html, jsp, menu, switch-statement

hi i want to know how to get html element and use them with switch statements.

```
<div id="hori">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Aerospace</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Automotive</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Energy</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">IC Engines</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">IT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Training</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Wind</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Turbo</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

<div id="verti">
<ul>
<li><a href="#1">Internal</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">Demos</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">Best Practice</a></li>
<li><a href="#4">Marketing</a></li>
<li><a href="#5">Papers & Public</a></li>
<li><a href="#6">Validation</a></li>
<li><a href="#7">Training</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

here the horizontal and vertical menus will be in the same page.the vertical menus is same for all horizontal menus for example.hori-main menus verti:sub menus.

1. aerospace:

   - internal
   - demo
2. automotive:

   - internal
   - demo

if the user click any of the main menus the mode should be changed accordingly.
if i click internal under aerospace,related table should be displayed in the same page without postback.

here is my jsp page which will display a html table binded with database

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");

 java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());

  psmnt1 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into file12(id,file_path,file_date) values(?,?,'"+ sqlDate+"')");

 psmnt1.setString(1, concat);

  psmnt1.setString(2, f.getPath());


  psmnt=connection.prepareStatement("select * from file12");

  rs=psmnt.executeQuery();

 int s=psmnt1.executeUpdate();
if(s>0)
{
System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
}
else
{
System.out.println("Error!");
}
}

catch(Exception e)
{
out.print("-----------error--------------"+e);
}
%>
<table cellpadding="15" border="1">
<%
 while(rs.next()){
%>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString(1)%> </td>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%> </td>
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%> </td>
</tr>
<%}%>
</table>
```

Comment: Iframe is good idea, but for that you should have good knowledge of javascript, for eg-> event handling and adding iframe dynamically to DOM. I can't mention everything here. To start with make a jsp page which contains the code you wrote in the question, this jsp page will be inserted into your page as iframe. So when a user clicks on an menu you have to get(using javascript) which vertical menu user has selected clicked on and the corresponding horizontal menu.

Comment: Once you have horizontal menu and vertical sub-menu , load the iframe(using javascript) and pass the Hor. and Ver. menu as query string to the jsp page. The jsp can get the menu data using request.getParameter() and display data accordingly. We use these kind of techniques in real projects. I hope this helps you theoretically.

Comment: @ravi jain:i will try...do u have any sample or link .

Comment: Sorry, i cannot provide you any sample because i am not allowed to share source code of projects. I don't even have any link to share because the technique which i suggested is a part of our project design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**if the user click any of the main menus the mode should be changed accordingly. if i click internal under aerospace,related table should be displayed in the same page without postback.**

Without postback it's not possible, jsp is not asp , in jsp there is nothing like postback.
Try some other strategy to achieve the required functionality(like ajax)

Comment: use of iframe will do,i need some idea on how to implement the above concept.

Comment: chk this its a new thread  i have started...
link:"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494013/retrieving-files-from-database-by-their-path-in-jsp"