# switch statement using enum

Tags: html, jsp, enums, switch-statement

i want to use switch statement with my menus.what i have did in my jsp page:

```
String menu1=request.getParameter("aero");
String menu2=reqStringuest.getParameter("auto");

String smenu1=request.getParameter("int");
String smenu2=request.getParameter("dem");

Enum str {menu1,menu2,smenu1,smenu2}
```

i want to know whether i have declared  enum correctly.
how to use them with the switch as iam new to jsp,this is the first time iam using the switch statement in my program. 
 i have posted a question 2 days before related to switch.
 the link : [using html list elements with switch stament and binding the list with database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313430/using-html-list-elements-with-switch-stament-and-binding-the-list-with-database)

here is my html code:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li id="aero" ><a href="sample2.jsp">aerospace</a></li>
        <li id="auto"><a href="sample2.jsp">automotive</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li id="int"><a href="sample2.jsp">internal</a></li>
        <li id="dem"><a href="sample2.jsp">demo</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do not write any java code in JSP.

Please consider moving it to separate class (where would be no issues with enums stc). This makes it possible to test your code in unit tests, increases maintanability and readabilty of your code.

Furthermore you can use some MVC framework (Struts, Spring MVC etc.)

Comment: :ok i understand.whether it is  possible to do the above thing in jsp.