# retrieving files from database by their path in jsp

Tags: mysql, html, jsp, hyperlink

i want to download a file by its path(local server path) which is stored in a database table ,i have done the coding part to view the database in a html table but i dont have any idea how to hyperlink the table in order to download the file(any type and size) from the ouput folder that is stored in a server.
here is the jsp code :

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*"%>

<%
String id=request.getParameter("id");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306  /ksa","root","root");  
Statement st=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select id,file_path,file_date from file12 where id like '"+id+"%'"); 
%>
<table cellpadding="15" border="1">
<%
while(rs.next()){
%>
<tr>
<td><%=rs.getString("id")%> </td>
<td><%=rs.getString("file_path")%> </td>
<td><%=rs.getString("file_date")%> </td>
</tr>
<%}%>
</table>
```

the above code will retrieve the table from database to html table.

Comment: @Satya:can u post ur last 2 comments,previous conversation is deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rs.getString("file_path")  returns a path is /home/Desktop/output/something.jpeg means you cannot download.Because when you click the given link surely it will show PAGE NOT FOUND (404) Exception.

"> click here to download the file

please note your URL it will look like

http://localhost:8080/prjname/home/Desktop/output/something.jpeg

So in this situation we can pass the path into one servlet ,through this servlet we can download the file.

Comment: yes my friend iam trying using a servlet as suggested by u.lets see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*"%>
 <%
   String id=request.getParameter("id");
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ksa","root","root");  
   Statement st=con.createStatement();
   ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select id,file_path,file_date from file12 where id like '"+id+"%'"); 
   %>
  <table cellpadding="15" border="1">
  <%
    while(rs.next()){
  %>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="<%=rs.getString("file_path")%>"> click here to download the file with  id :<%=rs.getString("id")%> </a> </td>

    </tr>
 <%}%>
</table>
```

Comment: i assumed that local server path is some thing like this 'http:\\localhost:8080\add\filename.doc'

Comment: can u giv the value of rs.getString("file_path") ??  i mean the filepath stored in db?

Comment: These files are in server rite?

Comment: i have given the path as /home/Desktop/....the file will be stored in this location and the path+filename will be stored in database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11008/discussion-between-ksa-and-tfool)

Comment: How are u accessing the server Then?? There shd be some mechanism to access server rite?

Comment: actually the content to be accessed outside the project shd be in webcontent...
move ur home folder and it sub folder to webcontent of ur project cd and then try the same code..

Comment: did u found the solution of the problem

Comment: I think the problem is with the directry in which he placed that file

Comment: http://localhost:8080/home/adapco/NetBeansProjects/cd/web/output/aerodynamicsuzukihayabusa.jpg this is the correct path iam getting but i cant download the file.

Comment: The image is getting displayed?

Comment: @ravi jain:no u have any other idea.

Comment: I think the problem is with the url.. The url shd be something like this.. localhost:8080/projectName/filePath... 
The filePath here is the path under Webcontent folder of ur project cd..

Comment: Step 1 : Place all downloadable files under one directory lets say 'ABC' , 'ABC' directory must be under the root directory of your project. What you need to store into database is the path of file which starts from 'ABC' , Eg> ABC/dir1/dir2/file.jpg , and how to make it downloadable is answered by TFool in answer

Comment: @ravijain:the directory is inside my project folder.but still it is 404,probably the it looks under the localhost:8080/..././,if i put them inside tomcat work-catalina-localhost-myproject,it may work.